# Including multiple fields in a Postgres table index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm using Postgres 8.4 and I'm performing a search using ILIKE. Since I'm searching in 4 columns (containing text) from that table I was wondering if it's ok to create a single index for all the 4 columns and not an index for each column.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a complicated topic.  In general databases will not optimize a LIKE query unless it is anchored to the beginning.  If you are searching across 4 columns, then this is LIKEly not the case.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-types.html

> The optimizer can also use a B-tree
>   index for queries involving the
>   pattern matching operators LIKE and ~
>   if the pattern is a constant and is
>   anchored to the beginning of the
>   string — for example, col LIKE 'foo%'
>   or col ~ '^foo', but not col LIKE
>   '%bar'. However, if your database does
>   not use the C locale you will need to
>   create the index with a special
>   operator class to support indexing of
>   pattern-matching queries; see Section
>   11.9 below. It is also possible to use B-tree indexes for ILIKE and ~*, but
>   only if the pattern starts with
>   non-alphabetic characters, i.e.,
>   characters that are not affected by
>   upper/lower case conversion.

You may consider the full text support in postgresql if you are doing natural language queries (like a search engine)...

Comment: Or wait für 9.1 which will be able to use an index for LIKE and ILIKE: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/